# spring boot rest api : wrong with showing information

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jersey

I have written a rest API using spring boot and Jersy, I have problem with requests.
when I do a get request it show me the result for more than a hundred time.
this is my controller class

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
  @RequestMapping("/users")
public List<User> getAllUsers(){
    return new UserService().getAllUsers();
}
@RequestMapping("/users/{id}")
public User getUser(@RequestParam int id) {
    return new UserService().getUser(id);
}
}
```

and this is my service class

```
@Service
public class UserService {
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                             .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                             .addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
                             .addAnnotatedClass(UserProfile.class)
                             .buildSessionFactory();

public UserService() {

}

public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<User> users = session.createQuery("from User").list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return users;
}


public User getUser(int id) {
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    User user = session.get(User.class, id);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    return user;
}


}
```

this is the result showing

```
[{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":{"id":7,"name":"mohammad","email":"mohammadpakivand@gmail.com","userProfile":{"id":1,"lastName":"pakivand","number":"09362762537","user":
```

this User class has a one to one relation with UserProfile class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First. Your UserService is annotated as a Service. That means that an instance is created during bootstrapping Spring and that this UserService instance is put into the SpringContext. Your Restcontoller makes also part of the SpringContext. Then you can inject your service into your controller.

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

// Here is where the injection takes place
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

  @RequestMapping("/users")
public List<User> getAllUsers(){
    return userService.getAllUsers();
}
@RequestMapping("/users/{id}")
public User getUser(@RequestParam int id) {
    return userService.getUser(id);
}
}
```

Second.
Why do you use and commit a transaction during a read-only operation.

Third. What is the code of your User class?

Comment: I committed because I thought the reputation of showing the result is because of the session is open.
and the User class is below
    `@Entity
    @Table(name="user")
    public class User {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name="id")
 private int id;
 
 @Column(name="name")
 private String name;
 
 @Column(name="email")
 private String email;
 
 @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name="user_profile_id")
 private UserProfile userProfile;
 
 public User() {
  
 }`
...
//getter and setters

@Ronald van der List

Comment: I think your UserProfile class has a reference to your User class. That's why the userProfile property in your json is showing a user property, which has a userProfile property etc. That's why your json is nested with the same user. There is a great post on baeldung which explains this: [www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)